# reactjs -- adding more to state when compositing a component

Tags: reactjs

if I have a class

```
class Role extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            role: 'something',
            value: 1
        }
    }
    render() {
        let roleStatus = [];
        for (let key in this.state) {
            roleStatus.push(<p key={key}>{key}: {this.state[key]}</p>)
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {roleStatus}
                </div>

            </div>
        );
}
```

and then another class that uses composition (asrecommended by React doc)

```
class specialRole extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // I want to add some other attributes to this.state
    }
    render() {
        return <role />
    }
}
}
```

I want to be able to add another attribute, let's say `name`, to this.state, but when I use `setState` to add it, the render doesn't reflect to it. I'm wondering if it's because setState is not synchronized function. If that's the case, how should I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Aren't you mixing up local state & props? Any chance you can link to the docs you are referring to?

Comment: @Icepickle https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: But you seem to have misread that part, there it handles about having a more generic component rendered through a more specific component (if you refer to the WelcomeDialog and Dialog). WelcomeDialog has a state, Dialog is just a functional component without state (just renders through props). State is private, cannot be extended, props are your way to go

Comment: @Icepickle so should i transform my role component into a stateless one and just use props? And then set all the state in specialRole?

Comment: I was thinking about using inheritance until I saw that i shouldn't do it in React. To me it makes more sense to have one class inherit another basic class, but that doesn't seem to be the case for React?

Comment: Well it really depends on the fact if you really will do something useful for the role component with the state. As your code is set up now, I don't really see why you would need state in this case. Inheritance is indeed something that isn't really useful in react, as props and local state and reusability of components is just more useful. It also depends which state management you want to use in the future

Comment: This might be something useful to read in your case: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is think of it like a parent/child composition.

The parent has the logic and passes it to the child, which then displays it.

In your case, the parent should be Role, and the child component be something that renders Role's states, for example: RoleStatus.  In addition, you can have another component called SpecialRoleStatus. **Note the capitalized component names, component names should be capitalized.**

The composition would look something like this:

```
class Role extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    //lots of state, including special ones
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <RoleStatus normalState={this.state.normalState} />
        <SpecialRoleStatus specialState={this.state.specialState} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Also,** setState() won't behave like you want it to because it does not set the state of any other component other than its own component.